# Add leading zeros within string

Tags: regex, r

I have a series of column names that I'm trying to standardize.

```
names <- c("apple", "banana", "orange", "apple1", "apple2", "apple10", "apple11", "banana2", "banana12")
```

I would like anything that has a one digit number to be padded by a zero, so

```
apple
banana
orange
apple01
apple02
apple10
apple11
banana02
...
```

I've been trying to use `stringr`

```
strdouble <- str_detect(names, "[0-9]{2}")
strsingle <- str_detect(names, "[0-9]")

str_detect(names[strsingle & !strdouble])
```

but unable to figure out how to selectively replace/prepend...

Comment: Does `sub("([a-z])([0-9])$","\\10\\2",names)` help you ?

Comment: @etienne yes! Can you explain the "\\10\\2" construction for the replacement?

Comment: I added an answer with an explanation.

Comment: if you're just wanting to sort, you can use `gtools::mixedsort` like so `data.frame(x = sort(names), y = gtools::mixedsort(names))`

Comment: Fyi, `names` is a commonly used function. You might confuse yourself and others by using it for something else in your code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `sub("([a-z])([0-9])$","\\10\\2",names)` :

```
[1] "apple"    "banana"   "orange"   "apple01"  "apple02"  "apple10"  "apple11"  "banana02"
[9] "banana12"
```

It only changes the names where there is a single digit following a letter (the `$` is the end of the string).

The `\\1` selects the first block in `()` : the letter. Then it puts a leading 0, then the second block in `()` : the digit.

Answer (score 6):

Here's one option using negative look-ahead and look-behind assertions to identify single digits.

```
gsub('(?<!\\d)(\\d)(?!\\d)', '0\\1', names, perl=TRUE)
# [1] "apple"    "banana"   "orange"   "apple01"  "apple02"  "apple10"  "apple11"  "banana02" "banana12"
```

Answer (score 2):

**str_pad** from stringr:

```
library(stringr)

pad_if = function(x, cond, n, fill = "0") str_pad(x, n*cond, pad = fill)

s = str_split_fixed(names,"(?=\\d)",2)
#       [,1]     [,2]
#  [1,] "apple"  ""  
#  [2,] "banana" ""  
#  [3,] "orange" ""  
#  [4,] "apple"  "1" 
#  [5,] "apple"  "2" 
#  [6,] "apple"  "10"
#  [7,] "apple"  "11"
#  [8,] "banana" "2" 
#  [9,] "banana" "12"

paste0(s[,1], pad_if(s[,2], cond = nchar(s[,2]) > 0, n = max(nchar(s[,2]))))
# [1] "apple"    "banana"   "orange"   "apple01"  "apple02"  "apple10"  "apple11"  "banana02" "banana12"
```

This also extends to cases like going from `c("a","a2","a20","a202")` to `c("a","a002","a020","a202")`, which the other approaches don't cover.

The stringr package is based on stringi, which has all the same functionality used here, I'm guessing.

---

**sprintf** from base, with a similar approach:

```
pad_if2 = function(x, cond, n, fill = "0") 
  replace(x, cond, sprintf(paste0("%",fill,n,"d"), as.numeric(x)[cond]))

s0 = strsplit(names,"(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|$",perl=TRUE)

s1 = sapply(s0,`[`,1)
s2 = sapply(sapply(s0,`[`,-1), paste0, "")

paste0(s1, pad_if2(s2, cond = nchar(s2) > 0, n = max(nchar(s2))))
```

`pad_if2` has less general use than `pad_if`, since it requires `x` be coercible to numeric. Pretty much every step here is clunkier than the corresponding code with the packages mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Key is to identify single digit with $ and letter before digit. It could be tried:

```
gsub('[^0-9]([0-9])$','0\\1',names)
[1] "apple"    "banana"   "orange"   "appl01"   "appl02"   "apple10"  "apple11"  "banan02"  "banana12"
```

or look-ahead.

```
gsub('(?<=[a-z])(\\d)$','0\\1',names,perl=T)
```

Comment: Same as Matthew's but with `$` in place of `(?!\\d)`? Hmm, I guess more like a combo of Matthew's and Etienne's...